# simulating an observational dataset for a teaching example

Tags: r

I'm looking for help simulating an observational dataset in R where the correlated variables `Z` and `D` confound the relationship between the exposure (0/1) and the outcome (0-10).

This [`simstudy` example](https://www.rdatagen.net/post/be-careful/) is close, but I'm not certain about the formulas. I like the potential outcomes approach shown, and would like to bake in an effect (exposure → outcome) of 1.5 that I can recover once controlling for `Z` and `D`.

[image]

Comment: The [faux](https://debruine.github.io/faux/) package may also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a single data set with the specified characteristics, you could try:

```r
set.seed(4410)

Z        <- sample(100, 1000, TRUE)
D        <- Z + rnorm(1000, 0, 20)
D        <- round((D - min(D)) / diff(range(D)) * 600 + 200)
Exposure <- rbinom(1000, 1, (D + Z) / 1000)
Outcome  <-  rbinom(1000, 10,  (Exposure + 2.3) / 6.6 + (D + Z)/2000)

df <- data.frame(Exposure, Outcome, Z, D)
```

Note that this gives all integers, and each of the integers is within the specified range for each variable:

```r
head(df)
#>   Exposure Outcome  Z   D
#> 1        0       4  8 344
#> 2        0       5 15 372
#> 3        1       7 39 549
#> 4        0       6 66 508
#> 5        1       9 78 570
#> 6        1       9 28 347

lapply(df, range)
#> $Exposure
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> $Outcome
#> [1]  1 10
#> 
#> $Z
#> [1]   1 100
#> 
#> $D
#> [1] 200 800
```

We can confirm that `Z` and `D` are positively correlated with each other, and that both `Z` and `D` are positively correlated with `Exposure`:

```r
cor(df$Z, df$D)
#> [1] 0.832381
cor(df$Z, df$Exposure)
#> [1] 0.235582
cor(df$D, df$Exposure)
#> [1] 0.2367981
```

Without taking the confounders into account, the effect of `Exposure` is about 1.8:

```r
lm(Outcome ~ Exposure, data = df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Outcome ~ Exposure, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     Exposure  
#>       6.127        1.795
```

But taking the confounders into account, we can see that the coefficient for `Exposure` is 1.5

```r
summary(lm(Outcome ~ Exposure + Z + D, data = df))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Outcome ~ Exposure + Z + D, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.5112 -0.9401  0.0876  0.9671  4.1952 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 3.8034249  0.2496879  15.233  < 2e-16 ***
#> Exposure    1.5000019  0.0900666  16.654  < 2e-16 ***
#> Z           0.0035773  0.0027056   1.322    0.186    
#> D           0.0045452  0.0006929   6.560 8.65e-11 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.364 on 996 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.378,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.3761 
#> F-statistic: 201.7 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This looks spot on @Allen_Cameron

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```r
set.seed(123)
b <- replicate(2500, {
  Z <- runif(250, 0, 100)
  D <- scales::rescale(Z + rnorm(250, 0, 20), to=c(200, 800))
  q_esposure <- -5 + (1/sd(Z))*Z + (1/sd(D))*D
  exposure <- rbinom(250, 1, plogis(q_esposure))
  error <- rnorm(250, 0, 1)
  outcome <-  error + .01*D + .1*Z
  outcome <- scales::rescale(outcome, to=c(0, 8.5))
  outcome <- outcome + 1.5*exposure
  lm(outcome ~ Z + D + exposure)$coef
})

rowMeans(b)
#>  (Intercept)            Z            D     exposure 
#> -0.722225550  0.049755855  0.004978287  1.500040770
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @davearmstrong! Stepped away from the computer for a minute but eager to examine.