# simulating an observational dataset for a teaching example (with collider)

Tags: r

I would like to simulate a dataset with mediation (X → S → Y), confounding (X ← C → Y), and a collider (X → S ← E) where `S` is a mediator and collider.

[image]

I've attempted to follow several useful resources:

- [This helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971002/841405) to my previous question
- [This observational data simulation tutorial](https://evalf20.classes.andrewheiss.com/example/synthetic-data/#specific-examples-1)
- [This collider simulation example](https://bookdown.org/content/4857/the-haunted-dag-the-causal-terror.html#the-haunted-dag.)

Here are my core parameters:

```
n    <- 1000 

b_xs <- 5    # direct effect of X on S (s +5 if x==1 where s is a count)
b_sy <- 0.05 # direct effect of S on Y (y +0.05 for each additional 1 s)

# direct effect of X on Y (y +1.25 if x==1 where y ranges from 0-10)
b_xy <- 1.25  

# indirect effect of X on Y = 0.25
b_xs*b_sy

# total effect of X on Y = 1.5: 
b_xy + b_xs*b_sy
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding how the DAG should work (always possible), I want to recover a total effect of X → Y of 1.5 after adjusting for the confounding variable C.

These parameters are mostly illustrative and could change. I want all effects to be positive.

```
# values could change, but should be positive effects
b_es  <- 0.6 # direct effect of E on S (s +0.6 if e==1)
b_ey  <- 0.5 # direct effect of E on Y (y +0.5 if e==1)
b_cx <-  0.1 # direct effect of C on X (x more likely if c==1)
b_cy <-  0.5 # direct effect of C on Y (y +0.5 if c==1)
```

The last piece of setup is to run `tabluate()` to generate starting integer values for Y that range from 0 to 10 with a mean of 4.

```
# for tabulate() to create base values for y
# https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/443558/23607
k <- 10      # sample integers from 1 to k
m <- 4       # desired baseline mean for y 
m_ <- m_+1   # shift up by 1 since sample from 1:10 not 0:10
z <- n*m_

# for tabulate() to create base values for s
ks <- 8       # sample integers from 1 to ks
ms <- 4       # desired baseline mean for s 
ms_ <- ms+1   # shift up by 1 since sample from 1:10 not 0:10
zs <- n*ms_
```

Here is my approach:

```
# simulate
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(21)
d <-
# create exogenous variables e and c, as well as baseline for y
  tibble(
    e = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = .5),
    c = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = .5),
    y_base = tabulate(sample.int((k-1)*n, z-n) %% n + 1, n)
    ) %>% 
# create x as a function of c
  mutate(
    x_score = c + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  # scale score down to 0.05 to 0.95 to create a probability of x
    x_probability = scales::rescale(x_score, to = c(0.05, 0.95)),
  # randomly generate a 0/1 variable using that probability
    x = rbinom(n, 1, x_probability)
    ) %>% 
# create s as a function of x and e
  mutate(
    s_effect = (b_xs*x) + (b_es*e),
    s = s_base + s_effect + rnorm(n, 0, sd = 0.5)
    ) %>%
# create y as a function of x, s, and e
  mutate(
    y_effect = (b_xy*x) + (b_sy*s)/max(s) + (b_ey*e) + (b_cy*c),
    y = y_base + y_effect + rnorm(n, 0, sd = 1),
    y = floor(scales::rescale(y, to = c(min(y_base), 10)))
  ) %>%
  select(x, y, c, s, e)
```

My coefficients are off (e.g., coef x does not change when adding `c`), and I'm wondering if there is a better/easier way. Here's what I think I'm aiming to produce:

```
tidy(lm(y ~ x, data = d))              # naive estimate of total X→Y effect should be biased
tidy(lm(y ~ x + c, data = d))          # controlling for c should recover total X→Y effect 1.5
tidy(lm(y ~ x + c + s, data = d))      # adding s should open the X→S←E→Y path and introduce bias
tidy(lm(y ~ x + c + s + e, data = d))  # adding s + e should give unbiased direct X→Y effect 1.25
```

I might be wrong about the target result for `x` in the final model, `lm(y ~ x + c + s + e, data = d)`. I think conditioning on `s` gives me a biased estimate of the direct (not total) effect and adding `e` closes the biasing pathway.

Comment: I don’t see you using b_cy anywhere in your code—or anywhere where c influences y_effect not through c. So that would explain why x would not change when adding c to the model.

Comment: Ah, good catch @clementzach. Thanks for lending your eyes. I'm going to work on it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution based on the [`simstudy` package](https://kgoldfeld.github.io/simstudy/index.html), following from [this tutorial](https://www.rdatagen.net/post/be-careful/).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(data.table)
library(simstudy)

# create exogenous variables C and E
def2 <- defData(varname = "C", formula = .5, dist = "binary")
def2 <- defData(def2, varname = "E", formula = .3, dist = "binary")

# create the exposure X as a function of C
def2 <- defData(def2, "X", formula = "-1 + 1 * C", dist = "binary", link = "logit")

# S and Y have two potential outcomes

# create S as a function of X and E
def2 <- defData(def2, "S.0", dist = "poisson",
                formula = "1 + 0.5 * X + 0.5 * E", link = "log")
def2 <- defData(def2, "S.1x", dist = "poisson",
                formula = "1.5 + 0.5 * X + 0.5 * E", link = "log")
def2 <- defData(def2, "S.1", formula = "pmax(S.0, S.1x)", dist = "nonrandom")

# create Y as a function of S, E, and X (via Y0 and Y1)
def2 <- defData(def2, "e", formula = 0, variance = 0.05, dist = "normal")

def2 <- defData(def2, "Y0", formula = "0 + 0.5*S.0 + 0.5*E + e", dist = "nonrandom")
def2 <- defData(def2, "Y1", formula = "0.1 + 0.5*S.1 + 0.5*E + e", dist = "nonrandom")

# set observed S and Y based on value of X
def2 <- defData(def2, "S_obs", formula = "S.0 + (S.1 - S.0) * X", dist = "nonrandom")
def2 <- defData(def2, "Y_obs", formula = "Y0 + (Y1 - Y0) * X", dist = "nonrandom")


set.seed(25)
dt <- genData(1000, def2)

# I have not figured out how to simulate integers from 0-10 for Y
# This is a temporary hack
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(Y0 = abs(floor(Y0)),
         Y1 = abs(floor(Y1)),
         Y_obs = abs(floor(Y_obs)))
```

The true effect of X is:

```
dt[, mean(Y1 - Y0)]
# [1] 1.571
```

Conditioning on `C` does not recover the effect.

```
tidy(lm(Y_obs ~ X + C, data = dt))

## A tibble: 3 × 5
#  term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)   1.29      0.0723    17.9   3.01e- 62
#2 X             2.96      0.0958    30.9   2.02e-147
#3 C             0.0172    0.0932     0.184 8.54e-  1
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33577913)

Comment: I don't have a new question. This answer is the makings of a possible solution to the original question.

Comment: Checking in from Review: I think this question + answer look okay and primarily are about a programming question. I've edited this answer slightly to clarify intent in the opening line.